# JPA not updating column with Converter class

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

I'm using a Converter class to store a complex class as JSON text in mySQL. When I add a new entity, the Converter class works as intended. However, when I update the entity, the data in the complex class is not updated in the database but it's updated in memory. Other attributes such as Lat and Long are updated. The breakpoint I placed at the *convertToDatabaseColumn* method and it did not trigger on update.

**Object Class**

```
public class Project {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    private String city;
    private String state;
    private String country;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private StatusType status;
    private String street;
    private double latitude;
    private double longitude;
    @Convert(converter=ProjectPropertyConverter.class)
    private ProjectProperty property;
}

public class ProjectProperty {

    private String description;
    private List<String> projectImgs;
    private Boolean hasImages;
}
```

**Property Converter Class**

```
@Converter (autoApply=true)
public class ProjectPropertyConverter implements AttributeConverter<ProjectProperty, String> {

    @Override
    public String convertToDatabaseColumn(ProjectProperty prop) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(prop);
            return jsonString;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
            return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public ProjectProperty convertToEntityAttribute(String jsonValue) {
        try {
            ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            ProjectProperty p = mapper.readValue(jsonValue, ProjectProperty.class);

            if(p.getProjectImgs().isEmpty())
            {
                p.setHasImages(Boolean.FALSE);
            }
            else
            {
                p.setHasImages(Boolean.TRUE);
            }          
            return p;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.print(e.toString());
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

**Method to Update Database**

```
public void modifyEntity(Object entity, String query, HashMap params) {
    try {
        tx.begin();
        em.flush();
        tx.commit();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: Quick update: I checked the mySQL log and the UPDATE statement is missing the JSON text string that is suppose to represent the ProjectProperty attribute if I change multiple attributes. If I change just ProjectProperty -> description, there is no UPDATE statement at all in the logs.

Comment: How do you expect your JPA provider to know you have changed the *internals* of a non-Entity field? Mutable non-entity types could be "proxied" but it depends whether your JPA provider allows that possibility.

Comment: Bare with me as I'm new to coding in general. If I can create a new Project with ProjectProperty's internal values populated and persisted to the database and then retrieved, how is that not considered an Entity field?

Comment: Going back to the search results, I came across this post which is similar to my situation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676217/data-lost-because-of-jpa-attributeconverter?rq=1

I then tried using a deep copy of the ProjectProperty and set it back into the Project.ProjectProperty before the Transaction commit.

Attempt 1:

Comment: Disregard my previous comment, I timed out on the edit.

Going back to the search results, I came across this post which is similar to my situation.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34676217/data-lost-because-of-jpa-attributeconverter?rq=1

After some testing, I found that I need to clone ProjectProperty, empty it with a new ProjectProerty, persist it, set the attribute back using the clone, and persist it again. It works but I'm not comfortable with it because I'm calling calling transaction commit twice.

Comment: The problem is that ProjectProperty presumably has mutator methods. A JPA provider wont know that they have been called since the "entity" just sees an object reference. A "proxy" is something a JPA provider *can* use instead of the actual ProjectProperty so that it can intercept mutating methods and hence know what is changed. Since ProjectProperty is your own type there will be no such "proxy" hence the JPA provider doesnt know you changed the field internals UNLESS you replace the field value. Which should explain the problem

Comment: Are there any updates regarding this topic? I mean, some kind of best practice or smth else

Answer (score 3):

I came here looking for same answers. Turns out the problem is JPA doesn't know that your object is dirty. This was solved by implementing equals()/hashcode() methods on this complex objects. In your example, implement equals and hashcode for ProjectProperty

Once that is done, JPA is able to identify via these methods that the underlying object is dirty and converts and persists.